# XLR AT2020 Problem

Tags: microphone, xlr, interface

My Audio Technica AT2020 is plugged into a interface called the Scarlett solo.

For some odd reason I will be recording when randomly I will look at the audio bar and is not going up and down it's almost like I turned my mic off or something. I check the device and it says Working properly. I use OBS for recording or Open Broadcaster Sofware.

Comment: Is the audio actually recorded fine after the fact or is there a drop-out when the audio bar/meter stopped moving?

Comment: There is a drop-out when the audio bar/meter stopped moving.I will be recording and even in skype calls suddenly the mic doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, what are you system specs? Hard drive speed & RAM are my first concerns.

Also, do you know what your buffer size & latency is set to is set to in the Focusrite mixcontrol software (or other hardware settings)? Something like this: http://i.imgur.com/d26fIvj.png

Comment: Could this be a phantom power problem? or a loose jack or damaged cable? If the meter you talk about is on the Scarlett Solo, then I doubt it's a software problem.

Comment: Is the sound *actually* dropping out, or are you simply *looking* at the "audio bar"? Capturing audio without actually LISTENING to it is like flying blind.  Which "device" is "working properly"?  It seems unlikely this is related to the microphone, cable, or mic preamp/interface. It sounds like a software problem from your symptoms.

Comment: The sound just stops working like the audio bar for the microphone with just stop going up and down with the tones of my voice. And will sometimes freeze at the last sound it picks up and stays there.